# Can you identify the set for this red LEGO snowmobile?

Tags: set-identification

A long time ago I got this pieces of what seems to be a snowmobile but I don't know if it is complete (with the pieces shown in the picture) or what would be the expected<sup>1</sup> way of building it.

[image: mysterious set]

I have tried several configurations and none of them are completely satisfying. I don't know what was the original intention with the skis, the saws and the rear end.

Could somebody help?

---

<sup>1. Understanding, of course, that with a LEGO you have the freedom to try different configurations, not just the one suggested by instructions.</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [1710-1: Snowmobile](https://brickset.com/sets/1710-1/Snowmobile) (or the variant that came in a box, [1730-1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=1730-1)):

[image: set image]

[The chain saw piece only appears in a few sets with that color.](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=6117&in=S)

Here you can see the instructions.

[image]